# MongoDB Indexes Based on $in?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design, mongodb-indexes, database

I have a query that looks through log entries which are tagged by priority.

```
db.logs.find({
    environment: "production",
    priority: {
        $in: ["debug", "info"]
    }
}).sort({
    timestamp: -1
})
```

This collection is now over *3GB* and these queries are taking upwards of **45 seconds** to return.

Queries like the following, still return in under a second:

```
db.logs.find({
    environment: "production",
    priority: "info"
}).sort({
    timestamp: -1
})
```

It appears that my indexes aren't doing anything to help.  Here's what I've tried:

```
{ "_id" : 1}
{ "timestamp" : -1}
{ "priority" : 1 , "timestamp" : -1}
{ "environment" : 1 , "timestamp" : -1}
{ "environment" : 1 , "priority" : 1 , "timestamp" : -1}
```

None of these appear to be helping me.  Is there some way to create indexes based around groupings?  (i.e. an index for all messages where `priority: { $in: ["foo", "bar", "bin"] }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This excellent blog post](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/) explains your exact scenario. Essentially the indexing is sorting *first* independently and then using your index. To use the range query (`$in`) you should do the indexing in opposite order: `{timestamp: -1, priority: 1}`.

Also use `.explain` to see what your query is doing. With `scanAndOrder: true` it has to do a full scan of the collection and attempt to sort in memory which is going to take a long time.

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you!  I've been banging my head against the wall about this one for a while now...